# Can anyone tell me anything about this sword?

Tags: weapons, spain, identification, sword

Can anyone tell me anything about this sword? It hangs in my husband's great grandmother's house for as long as he can remember.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the words on the sword and can you add a picture of the other side?

Comment: @KenGraham "Made in Spain", which suggests a modern (XX century) manufacture

Comment: (that, or that my latin is way worse than I thought :-D)

Comment: The design on the blade looks stamped on rather than engraved and the whole thing looks cheap. The "Made in Spain" marking suggests not only comparatively recent manufacture but also that it was intended for an export (souvenir?) market.

Comment: I would expect a genuine sword of this style to have some sort of cutting edge to it and not to have paint/gilding flaking off.

Comment: @SteveBird - I'd agree. The Spanish word for "Spain" is "Espania". That was pretty clearly intended to be read by an English-speaking person.

Answer (score 8):

First, it's probably a sword made in Toledo, Spain. This city is famous for its ancient sword industry. Today, the sword industry in Toledo forges both high-quality swords and souvenirs of industrial quality (not only recreations from Spanish history; they make Japanese katanas, swords from movies such as The Lord of the Rings and Conan movies, etc.)

And second, I've found [a similar sword on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Toledo-Colada-Del-Cid-Steel-Long-Sword-Made-in-Spain-Measures-29-Long-/151055460718), wich is a recreation of Colada. According to the epic poem "Cantar de mio Cid / The poem of the Cid", Colada was one of two legendary swords used by the most renowned Spanish (Castillian) knight, [Rodrigo Diaz de Vivar "El Cid Campeador"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Cid). The sword is probably only a fiction from the poem, but El Cid was a historical warrior.